# Application crashes with core dump on RHEL7

Tags: gtk, rhel7

Application crashes with core dump on RHEL7.
When we analysed the dump file could see attached error.[image]

Is the issue related to gtk used while building the application or the gtk packages installed on the machine where we are trying to deploy the application.
Please suggestion any pointers if any other info needed.

Comment: You will need to debug your application. Download GTK+'s debugging symbols (I don't know how to do this on RHEL, sorry), compile your application with debugging symbols, run your application under gcc, and produce a backtrace when it does crash. Read through the backtrace; the function at the top is not necessarily the one that's responsible for the crash. In particular, find the last part of your code that gets called before the crash, and search there for possible errors.

Comment: The issue arises at the very first scroll even.

Comment: Okay, so you can reproduce the issue. That just gives you more incentive to use the debugger. We can't solve your problem in any other way; sorry.